# Change the color of legend symbol highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, legend

Is it possible to change the legend symbol color in Highcharts? 
For example [demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/symbolpadding/) contains two series and the symbols in legend are in blue and black (same as the series).

I couldn't find any `symbolColor` param in the documentation. How do I change them both to say black?

```
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    floating: true,
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: 90,
    y: 45,
    symbolPadding: 20,
    symbolWidth: 50,
    symbolColor: '#000000' ?????
},
```

[image]

Comment: Having colour of the legend different to that of series doesn't make sense to me. Legend is used depict what each series is, and in Highcharts, can also be used to show/hide series. May I ask why you need the legend to be of different colour than the series?

Answer (score 6):

Add `color` for the legend in each series.

```
series: [{color: '#000000',     //change here
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {color: '#000000',                   //change here
            data: [95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1]
        }]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nsr2p2j/50/)

Comment: @albert Did you changed the color and try ? Check http://jsfiddle.net/6nsr2p2j/3/

Answer (score 6):

The Highcharts 4.X source does look for a `legendColor` parameter for a series/point, however you can't (as far as I know) set it without it being a user option.

If you wrap the `colorizeItem` function of the `Legend` class you can set the `legendColor` attribute, and then utilize it quite easily. For example, wrap:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'colorizeItem', function (proceed, item, visible) {
        item.legendColor = item.options.legendColor;
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

And usage in your chart options:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        legendColor: 'black',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fypopsnc/5/) of how it looks.

Comment: the same fiddle to the answer below, and neither work for me

Comment: @albert I updated the fiddle. Works in Highcharts 4.X. I might see if I find something for 5.X, but currently this is a legacy fix.

Comment: With small change in your code chart should work in 5.X http://jsfiddle.net/fypopsnc/7/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/bym59w2p/

The colors of the legend items are updated when the series color gets an update. However, the legend will not change until clicked upon. When adding this bit of code:

```html
this.chart.addSeries({
    showInLegend: false
  });
  this.chart.redraw();
}
```

You are adding an empty data serie, which is not visible in the legend but does reset the legend area. Also by adding a duration to 1, you will not or hardly see the color change. Maybe this helps you or anyone else trying to find this answer.

See below for the plotOptions bit, or click the jsfiddle link above to see it in action.

```html
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        stacking: 'normal',
        animation: {
         duration: 1
        },
        events: {
          "afterAnimate": function () {
            var colorsArr = ['red','yellow','green'];
            var nameArr = ['test','test2','test3'];
            var countI;
            for(countI=0;countI<this.data.length;countI++){
              switch(this.name){
                case nameArr[0]:
                  this.color = colorsArr[0];
                  this.data[countI].color = colorsArr[0];
                  break;
                case nameArr[1]:
                  this.color = colorsArr[1];
                  this.data[countI].color = colorsArr[1];
                  break;
                case nameArr[2]:
                  this.color = colorsArr[2];
                  this.data[countI].color = colorsArr[2];
                  break;
              }
            }  
            this.chart.addSeries({
             showInLegend: false
            });
            this.chart.redraw();
         }
        }
    }
}
```