# How can I set the legend symbol color for a series when using colorByPoint?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a column chart with two series (this year, last year), where I want to set the colour for certain "groups"of columns to represent seasons, like this:

[image]

To do this, I've set the `colors` for each series, and used the `colorByPoint` option. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zhpc6r5/).

Notice that the chart legend uses the same grey color for the symbol for both series. (I'm not even sure where that grey color comes from - it's not one from the "palette" of colours in either series).

**How can I set the legend symbol color for each series?** (Ideally, I'd want to use a darker grey for the "This year" series, to reflect the fact that the colors are darker for all the points in that series).

*NOTE: although there are other ways to set the colors for each data point, such as using an array of objects as the `data` parameter that includes a color setting, I don't want to do this, because in my real-life example the data comes from a CSV file via the `data` module - and so I don't have the ability to use objects in that way.*

Comment: @HalvorStrand: Thanks, but sadly not. See http://jsfiddle.net/9u0c35tp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36115475/2732991) I updated the code to support the newest version.

If you wrap `colorizeItem` function of the `Legend` class you can use a `legendColor` attribute:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'colorizeItem', function(proceed, item, visible) {
        var color = item.color;
        item.color = item.options.legendColor;
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        item.color = color;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

And still you apply a `legendColor`:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        legendColor: 'black',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

See [this updated JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/9zhpc6r5/1/) of it in use.